# Passing variables from PHP to Perl using POST

Tags: html, perl, cgi

This one is a tad frustrating.

If I run this perl script ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw/:standard/;              # load standard CGI routines
my $query = new CGI;

my $club5   = $query->param('club5');
my $messagetext = $query->param('messagetext');

print header,                       # create HTTP header
    start_html('Hello World'),      # start of HTML
    h1('Hello World'),              # level 1 headers
    h1($club5),
    h1($messagetext),
    end_html;                       # end of HTML

1;
```

from a remote Chrome browser with

```
http://www.<hostname>/cgi-bin/message_test.pl?club5=coop9&messagetext=test
```

the correct page is produced. But if I then execute this PHP program ...

```
<?php

$user_id = "10006";

echo <<<END
<html>
<head>

<title>Send Message</title>
</head>

<BODY bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
<br>
<table width="450px" height="150px" align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#e8e8e8">

<form action="http://<hostname>/cgi-bin/message_test.pl" method="post">

<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="user_id" VALUE="$user_id">

<tr align="center" valign="top">
<td>
<br>
<font face="Verdana" size="2">

<input name="messagetext" type="text" size="64">
<br>
<br>
<br><center>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="SEND">
</font>
</td>
</tr>

</form>

</table>

</body>
</html>
END;

?>
```

from the same browser with

```
http://<hostname>/message_test.php
```

nothing is returned. I swear I had something similar this running a year ago. Is there something new I should be aware of when passing (hidden) variables to Perl using HTTP POST?

Comment: Before I look further: `<form action="http://<hostname>message_test.pl" method="post">` doesn't seem to agree with the URL: `http://www.<hostname>/cgi-bin/message_test.pl?club5=coop9&messagetext=test`. 
Are you sure it's not supposed to be `<form action="http://<hostname>/cgi-bin/message_test.pl" method="post">` ?

Comment: Good catch, but I added that directory for clarity(!?) I've edited the post.

Comment: And what you're expecting to see? I don't get the REQUEST - RESPONCE order.

Comment: Perl should spit out the same web page with 'Hello World' and the 2 variables displayed that we get in the first instance. BTW in that first instance message_test.pl permissions are 755 and it runs OK, but if I chmod to 777 I get an internal server error! Anybody know if there is some apache directive that messes with the POSTing of CGI parameters? Anyway, as I said, this was all working a while ago, but as the man says, perhaps - "Things have changed."

Comment: removed PHP tag. PHP obviously has nothing to do here as it's a question about HTML form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because your browser incorrectly guesses what you meant by your invalid HTML.

It worked after I changed

```
<table ...>
<form ...>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="user_id" VALUE="$user_id">
...
</form>
</table>
```

to

```
<form ...>
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="user_id" VALUE="$user_id">
<table ...>
...
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Excellent! No idea how you picked up on that. I guess the "thing that changed" was the newer chrome and safari browsers getting a little less forgiving. Thanks very much.

Comment: @softex, I tested with Firefox

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, shouldn't

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="user_id" VALUE="$user_id">
```

be

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="user_id" VALUE="<? echo $user_id; >">
```

?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because the HTML part is inside `heredoc` operator `<<<END`

Comment: No, because it's within a heredoc (note the `echo <<<END`), where variable substitution occurs.